# Guzzle fatal error using Craft Guzzle client

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, api, guzzle

Using the code below to get 3rd party API

```
    $uri = $baseUri . '/area/' . $areaId . '.geojson?api_key=' . $mapAPIkey;

    $client = Craft::createGuzzleClient();
    $response= $client->request('GET',  $uri);
    $data = $response->getBody();
    return $data;
```

Getting error

```
Class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface::getRequestTarget, Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface::withRequestTarget, Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface::getMethod, ...)
```

What is wrong? Ive been through half a dozen other plugins that use guzzle like this and they seem to be ok

Comment: What does your `composer.json` say – which version of `guzzlehttp/guzzle` are you using?

Comment: Plugin composer doesn't have a require guzzle. I though it was native to craft? Do I need to :
use GuzzleHttp;

Comment: Guzzle is required by Craft, though Craft's [composer.json allows both Guzzle 6 and Guzzle 7](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/composer.json#L43). If you're using Guzzle in your own code, you should add it to your own dependencies. Try requiring version 7 explicitly, maybe you've gotten version 6 for some reason and there's something going wrong there: `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.3`

Comment: Problem seems to have resolved itself  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5.5|^7.2.0"
Thanks for the reply